# FXCop casting Warning

Tags: c#, fxcop

I get the following error when running FXCop:

> CA1800 : Microsoft.Performance :
>   'obj', a variable, is cast to type
>   'Job' multiple times in method
>   'ProductsController.Details(int,
>   int)'. Cache the result of the 'as'
>   operator or direct cast in order to
>   eliminate the redundant castclass
>   instruction

Code:

```
        object obj = repository.GetJobOrPlace(jobId);//Returns  (object) place or (object) product

        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj is Job)
            {
                Job j = (Job) obj;
                Debug.WriteLine(j.Title);
            }
            else if (obj is Place)
            {
                Place p = (Place) obj;
                Debug.WriteLine(p.Title);
            }
        }
```

What's wrong with this? I can only see one cast: Job j = (Job) obj.

Comment: The "is" operator is also a cast as far as .NET is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's only one *cast* but there's also a *test*. So you can replace the first block with:

```
Job j = obj as Job;
if (j != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(j.Title);
}
```

That means the execution time test only needs to be performed once, instead of twice. It's a bit of a micro-optimisation - and in your case it would make the code a bit messier, as you'd need:

```
Job j = obj as Job;
if (j != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(j.Title);
}
else
{
    Place p = obj as Place;
    if (p != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p.Title);
    }
}
```

(Or declare and initialize `p` earlier, which wastes a test if `obj` is actually a `Job`...)

Comment: A minor detail: the first line should be "Job j = obj as Job;" With capitalized J in Job.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "as job" should be "as Job" ;-)

Comment: Darn it, Anders beat me to it :P