# Test if a Type implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I'm looping on the fields and properties on a given `Type` and I'd like to test if the field type or property Type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Maybe it sounds strange but I will parse fields/properties such as strings, integers and other types, but I also have some `ObservableCollection` for example and some custom types I defined that inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

So on my code, I'd like to do some tests based on the fact that the field or property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or not.

Comment: @Matthieu - Whoops, didn't see your comment before answering.

Comment: @Matthieu, the question you linked deals with something different. The OP did not state it, but he's most likely using reflection to iterate through properties and fields so you cannot use `is`.

Comment: @Guillaume Cogranne, can you confirm if the assumption I made in my answer is correct so that the question can be updated to remove ambiguities.

Comment: Yep, can't use "is", as i answered in some answers telling me to do it !

Comment: @João Angelo : You're right. OP should give a code example, often easier to figure the intent with that :)

Comment: Close Voters: this is not an exact duplicate of @Matthieu's linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx) or [`GetInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx):

```
static bool SupportsINotifyPropertyChanged(this Type type)
{
    return null != type.GetInterface(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged).FullName);
    // or
    // return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged));
}
```

Or a slightly more generic approach:

```
static bool SupportsInterface<T>(this Type type)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsInterface) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return type != null && type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: If I try : bool b = propertyType.GetInterface(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged).ToString()); I got this error : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'bool'

Comment: got the exact same error with FullName. In fact, this returns a string, not a boolean... Am I wrong ?

Comment: how to call these functions `SupportsINotifyPropertyChanged() & SupportsInterface()` to check any class has implement INotifyPropertyChanged ? show me how to call ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that when you say iterating through field and properties of a class you're referring to standard reflection, namely you have objects of type `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo`.

So for a `PropertyInfo` you can do the following:

```
var pi = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Now");

var result = pi.PropertyType.GetInterface("INotifiyPropertyChanged");

Console.WriteLine(result != null);
```

And for a `FieldInfo` is pretty similar and you would just need to use `fi.FieldType.GetInterface("INotifiyPropertyChanged")`.

---

**Update:** If you already have a object of `System.Type` then you can call `GetInterface` method directly on that object to check if instances of that given type implement a specific interface or not.

Comment: I havent a PropertyInfo but a System.Type : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370186/588868) is to use this pattern :

```
var anyObject = FromTheVoid();

var objAsINotifyPropertyChanged = anyObject as INotifyPropertyChanged;

if(objAsINotifyPropertyChanged != null)
{
     objAsINotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged += myHandled;
}
```

If fact, it depends on your needs (are you willing to reflect, call child class methods if available,etc.).

**[Edit]** ["FxCop: Do not cast unnecessarily" blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2005/09/08/424700.aspx) also explain why this pattern is better to use.

Comment: He's got a `System.Type` not an actual object of the type.

Comment: It's true that my answer does not applies directly, `<sarcastic>` so my answer is only bullshit and nobody will ever benefits from it as its content as it's so inaccurate and wrong. Everyone should downvote this post in this case. Even Microsoft should implement a special rule in the compiler to avoid such pattern `</sarcastic>`

Comment: I don't disagree that your code works for some folks, just the OP asked: *"I'm looping on the fields and properties on a given `Type` and I'd like to test if the field type or property Type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`."*

Comment: I just do not consider "useful but doesn't apply answer" merits down vote... but I won't debate it here... it's a religious question not suited for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as correct is not the best way to determine this, if you have a System.Type you just need to do this:

```
bool isNotifyPropertyChanged = typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged).IsAssignableFrom(mytype);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just do the following.

```
if (property.Type is INotifyPropertyChanged) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

Note, I'm assuming that you're looping through the properties using reflection, and that property is of type PropertyInfo.

Comment: Can I get a response on why this was rated down?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `Type` isn't a public property on `PropertyInfo` and `System.Type` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.